# HTML / JS Popup over multiple layered images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For a little private project I've a map that consists of multiple images, put over each other, each one with a different transparent part, so all of them together form the map. All images have the same size and start at 0,0 (to make it easy to align).

Now it would be nice to have popups for the different parts, but obviously only the top-most image get's all the mouse hovers...

```
<p style="position:relative">

    <img id="de_background" src="background.gif" style="position:absolute;left:0px;right:0px"/>
    <img id="de_10" src="1.gif" style="position:absolute;left:0px;right:0px" title="Title 1"/>
    <img id="de_12" src="2.gif" style="position:absolute;left:0px;right:0px" title="Title 2"/>
```

So, is there a clever trick to allow hover/popus also for the part of the image that isn't transparent? Can I somehow ask via JavaScript "Which of the images here is not transparent on this point?".

Answer (score 0):

You set transparent in CSS properties or gif images are transparet yet? and by the way, you don't wrote elements z-index

Comment: Transparent .gifs, nothing more. And you are right, should set it at least for the background (the order of the others is not important).

Answer (score 0):

Just use the display CSS property for all elements that you want to hide, apart from the first one. You can even apply the CSS property through JS  and toggle between hidden and the visible one.

```
.hiddenImg {
    display: none;
}
```

More info: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

Comment: I do not want to hide anything. I want to display all the images. I just want a popup depending on the answer to the question "is there a non-transparent part of which image here"?